# identical webpage looks different on virtual server instance and production instance

Tags: php, html, css, apache, internet-explorer-6

Basically I am looking to figure out what appears to be a CSS conflict in IE6 and ONLY IE6, but the CSS files are identical, so it's more involved and has made a few of us bash our heads against the wall.  I'm all for killing brain cells, but not this way.

I have an events listing that is separated by a bar image (in png format), but in IE6 on the production instance it looks all messed up and wrong, overlapping and just... well, wrong.  On all the virtual server dev branches everything looks wonderful in IE6, the spacing is correct, no overlaps, pure gold... so it's only the production site.  Only IE6.  I've looked into the compatibility mode thing, which doesn't apply to IE6 from what I understand.

Is there server settings that might be causing this?  I'm not very experienced with this kind of thing, but I'd like to put this behind us.  So please help if you have any idea.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Microsoft doesn't even support IE6 anymore. http://www.ie6countdown.com/ If any of your users are using IE6, you need to display a message telling them they MUST upgrade their browser for a secure browsing experience. According to Microsoft, only 0.9% of web users in the US use IE6.

Comment: Have you checked default font and zoom settings on each?

Comment: CSS is interpreted by the browser, which is client-side. Is something else generating your CSS, like a PHP script? Try pulling up the page in IE6 in both the production environment and the dev environment and **view source** for each and see what the differences are.

Comment: I wonder why you are using IE6, it is a very old browser. I dont even know if it has developer option available so you can see applied CSS?

Comment: HTML, CSS, JavaScript all run **"Client-Side"**.  The same browser does not care where the files come from all long as they load.  I'm thinking you got some URL's screwed up along the way so your CSS file or other resources are not found.  I'm making this as a comment since nobody could really answer your question without seeing your page.

Comment: I'd love to post the site, but it's all intranet, so we're a bit limited :(

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple reasons why a webpage can be rendered differently on another server:

- Check that you're using the same internet security and compatibility settings in your browser (this only applies to IE).
- Check that the domain name is not hardcoded anywhere.
- In general, check that all resources are correctly loaded. For example, the production server might be missing a critical CSS file. The best way to do so is with the browser's developer tools, which you must [download](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/confirmation.aspx?displaylang=en&id=18359) for IE6.
- It is less likely, but also possible, that this issue is caused by the longer latency to your production server. Make sure you do not access the browser's DOM before it has been constructed. On IE6, there may also be plenty of other timing issues. Try accessing your development and production server with increased latency from multiple sites.

Comment: Yeah I've gone through the compatibility thing, but it doesn't apply to IE6.  There's absolutely no hardcoding, all php calls.  I'll definitely add those tools and check it out.  I'm still a student and can't remember ever using IE6 haha.  I like how dev tools come loaded into chrome.  As for the final thing about the DOM, I'll have to mention this to our sysadmin and have him take a look.  I don't want to spend much more time on this one.  It is afterall for IE6 :\

Answer (score 0):

CSS is interpreted by the browser, which is client-side. Is something else generating your CSS, like a PHP script? Try pulling up the page in IE6 in both the production environment and the dev environment and **view source** for each and see what the differences are.

If there are differences, post the PHP code that generates this output and we can suggest what might cause those differences.

Comment: It looks like I've stumbled upon a plugin that has saved some lines of code in the DB which is why git hasn't overwritten any of the changes and would explain why everything would appear to be identical.

When you had mentioned looking at the source code I decided to give it a shot and noticed a jscript that had loaded in one instance, but not the other.  I figured plugins might be the cause, so I'm crossing my fingers until I get access to our prod admin area so I can check it out.  
  
Thanks for the prompt response

Answer (score 0):

On both instances type `javascript:alert(document.compatMode)` into the address bar and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> and verify that you get the same result on both sites. It might show [Quirks](http://www.quirksmode.org/) or CSS1/2 compat mode. The production server might, for example, add a DOCTYPE declaration on the very first line of the HTML page (it has no effect if it is not the first) - this will trigger Standards Compliance mode which will switch the CSS box model and the way tables are rendered.